Draggable Rows with the free version of MaterialUI x-data-grid
For the record, I know it's there in the Pro version.
What I want to know if it can be simulated in the non-Pro version, and a direction as to how to do so, if possible; perhaps integration with something else on top of it.
Someone else asked a similar question; his answer was to use a different library altogether.
Trying to weigh the viability of sticking with MUI(for free) vs just outright changing to a different (free) library like that guy.
